# Windows Server 2012 R2 DNS server monitoring tests fail

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012

I configured DNS server in my fresh Windows Server 2012 R2 installation and everything works fine - names are resolved to IP-s, but tests in the Monitoring tab of DNS server properties always fail. Both simple and recursive queries.

I do not use forwarders.
All tests with Dcdiag are passed.
What may cause this?